# Search Solr View with exposed filter fullsearch return no results

Tags: views, 8, search

I setup a Solr search index (Solr 7.7.1 and Search API Solr 3.2) with custom entities. I have several fields indexed and 2 of them are fulltext. Additionally :

- I setup the view with an exposed filter in a block (page view)
- No Ajax option is set
- I have a filter Search enabled : Fulltext Search with following options :

  - Expose this filter to visitors
  - Signle filter
  - Contains any of these words
  - Allow multiple selections
  - Parse mode : direct query
  - All Fulltextfields selected
- Exposed form settings

  - Exposed form in block : YES
  - Exposed for style : basic
- I also setup some facets on other fields

When I come to the page, all results are displayed by default. When searching for any term(s) via the Full-text textfield, I am getting blank results. Instead if I select some facet options, results do show up accordingly to the facets.

How can I get the Fulltext search to work?

Comment: In your Search API index, are your text fields (e.g. title, body, and the like) marked as "fulltext"?  Otherwise, searches will have to match full strings and not words.  Note that changing this will require a index rebuild.

Comment: Yes, the textfields are marked as "fulltext" and I re-indexed. Any tip on how I could go about debugging this issue of no results returned? I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours, I discovered that search_api_solr 8.x-3.7 was the issue. I downgraded using composer to the latest v2.7 and it works fine.